# HTML—putting (Apple Pages or MS Word) class tags on text

Tags: html, ms-word, wysiwyg

I want to generate html text that, when copy/pasted to a WYSIWYG editor like Word or Pages, has the text belonging to different style groups (like a css class), so that in the editor a user could e.g. change the font color for a particular group of text.

Is this possible?

---

**Edit**

Just to clarify, I'm wondering if there is some way to tag/add attributes to the HTML so that when it is transferred to a word processor, all text of that group can be restyled at once within the processor.

I don't need any changes in the processor to be carried back to HTML, this is a one-way flow of data.

---

**Edit 2**

I mean is there something to add to HTML text, that word processors (or just one in particular) can recognise as a "class" of sorts, so that you can then make bulk changes to all text of that group? Below is a screenshot of Mac Pages' "Style" groups for reference—is there someway I could copy HTML and paste it in this Pages document, so that Pages would know I'm pasting in e.g. "Heading Red" text?

[image: Pages' Paragraph Styles]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking, but format a Word document in such a way as you imagine then save it as an HTML file and look at the HTML. Word's round-trip HTML is not documented so this is the only way to find out the syntax.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the actual HTML text in a word processor such as MS Word or Pages, but changing the font color, text size, etc through the word processor's functions as you would while writing a document will not have any effect when the HTML is viewed in a browser.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant, I want to transfer (via clipboard) text from HTML to a processor one way (no intention of putting it back in HTML), but I'm hoping to somehow tag the text with style groups in the HTML that the processor will recognise. I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: Are you asking, for example, if your html has <p style:'font-size:24'>Your Text<p> that the word processor will recognize that 'Your Text' has a font size of 24? And then you can change that <p> tag's font all together?

Comment: No, I'm asking can I add a class of sorts, e.g. `<p class="heading-3">asdf</p>` so that in the word processor I can set styles for all text with class "heading-3" (e.g. changing font size or color)